# Error: "__construct() must be an array, none given"

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, twitter

With the following code in my controller, I was able to pass my OAuth access tokens into [J7mbo's TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php) and perform a query on the Twitter API version 1.1:

```
// Set access tokens here
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "My Oauth Access Token",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "My Oauth Access Token Secret",
    'consumer_key' => "My Consumer Key",
    'consumer_secret' => "My Consumer Secret"   
    );


$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json';
$getfield = '?username=somename';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

However, for security reasons, I read that the *consumer secret* should not be human readeable within the app. So I moved my OAuth access tokens away from my controller (see above) to the following location (see below):

> application\config\twitter_settings.php

```
<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');
    // Set access tokens here   
    $config['oauth_access_token'] = "My access token";
    $config['oauth_access_token_secret'] = "My access secret";
    $config['consumer_key'] = "My consumer key";
    $config['consumer_secret'] = "My ENCRYPTED consumer_secret";

/* End of file Settings.php */
```

and attempted to load my access tokens from my controller

```
$this->config->load('twitter_settings');   
$this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange');
```

Now I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure how to pass my OAuth access tokens to [J7mbo's TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php):

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to TwitterAPIExchange::__construct() must
>   be an array, none given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\twitter_app\theworks\core\Loader.php on line 1099 and
>   defined
>
> Filename: twitter/TwitterAPIExchange.php
>
> Line Number: 33
>
> Make sure you are passing in the correct parameters

Here is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {                   
        $this->config->load('twitter_settings');
        //$this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange');

        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json';
        $getfield = '?username=stackexchange';
        $requestMethod = 'GET';
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange(/* I need to pass the OAuth tokens here */);
        echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                     ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                     ->performRequest();        
    }
}

/* End of file search.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/search.php */
```

and here is [J7mbo's TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php) code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Twitter-API-PHP : Simple PHP wrapper for the v1.1 API
 * 
 * PHP version 5.3.10
 * 
 * @category Awesomeness
 * @package  Twitter-API-PHP
 * @author   James Mallison <me@j7mbo.co.uk>
 * @license  http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 * @link     http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php
 */
class TwitterAPIExchange 
{
    private $oauth_access_token;
    private $oauth_access_token_secret;
    private $consumer_key;
    private $consumer_secret;
    private $postfields;
    private $getfield;
    protected $oauth;
    public $url;

    /**
     * Create the API access object. Requires an array of settings::
     * oauth access token, oauth access token secret, consumer key, consumer secret
     * These are all available by creating your own application on dev.twitter.com
     * Requires the cURL library
     * 
     * @param array $settings
     */
    public function __construct(array $settings)
    {
        if (!in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) 
        {
            exit('You need to install cURL, see: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html');
        }

        if (!isset($settings['oauth_access_token'])
            || !isset($settings['oauth_access_token_secret'])
            || !isset($settings['consumer_key'])
            || !isset($settings['consumer_secret']))
        {
            exit('Make sure you are passing in the correct parameters');
        }

        $this->oauth_access_token = $settings['oauth_access_token'];
        $this->oauth_access_token_secret = $settings['oauth_access_token_secret'];
        $this->consumer_key = $settings['consumer_key'];
        $this->consumer_secret = $settings['consumer_secret'];
    }

    /**
     * Set postfields array, example: array('screen_name' => 'J7mbo')
     * 
     * @param array $array Array of parameters to send to API
     * @return \TwitterAPIExchange Instance of self for method chaining
     */
    public function setPostfields(array $array)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->getGetfield())) 
        { 
            exit('You can only choose get OR post fields.'); 
        }
        $this->postfields = $array;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set getfield string, example: '?screen_name=J7mbo'
     * 
     * @param string $string Get key and value pairs as string
     * @return \TwitterAPIExchange Instance of self for method chaining
     */
    public function setGetfield($string)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->getPostfields())) 
        { 
            exit('You can only choose get OR post fields.'); 
        }

        $this->getfield = $string;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get getfield string (simple getter)
     * 
     * @return string $this->getfields
     */
    public function getGetfield()
    {
        return $this->getfield;
    }

    /**
     * Get postfields array (simple getter)
     * 
     * @return array $this->postfields
     */
    public function getPostfields()
    {
        return $this->postfields;
    }

    /**
     * Build the Oauth object using params set in construct and additionals
     * passed to this method. For v1.1, see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1
     * 
     * @param string $url The API url to use. Example: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json
     * @param string $requestMethod Either POST or GET
     * @return \TwitterAPIExchange Instance of self for method chaining
     */
    public function buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    {
        if (strtolower($requestMethod) !== 'post' && strtolower($requestMethod) !== 'get')
        {
            exit('Request method must be either POST or GET');
        }

        $consumer_key = $this->consumer_key;
        $consumer_secret = $this->consumer_secret;
        $oauth_access_token = $this->oauth_access_token;
        $oauth_access_token_secret = $this->oauth_access_token_secret;

        $oauth = array( 
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce' => time(),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0'
        );

        $getfield = $this->getGetfield();

        if (!is_null($getfield))
        {
            $getfields = str_replace('?', '', explode('&', $getfield));
            foreach ($getfields as $g)
            {
                $split = explode('=', $g);
                $oauth[$split[0]] = $split[1];
            }
        }

        $base_info = $this->buildBaseString($url, $requestMethod, $oauth);
        $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
        $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
        $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

        $this->url = $url;
        $this->oauth = $oauth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the acual data retrieval from the API
     * 
     * @param boolean optional $return If true, returns data. 
     * @return json If $return param is true, returns json data.
     */
    public function performRequest($return = true)
    {
        if (!is_bool($return)) 
        { 
            exit('performRequest parameter must be true or false'); 
        }

        $header = array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($this->oauth), 'Expect:');

        $getfield = $this->getGetfield();
        $postfields = $this->getPostfields();

        $options = array( 
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
        );

        if (!is_null($postfields))
        {
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postfields;
        }
        else
        {
            if ($getfield !== '')
            {
                $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= $getfield;
            }
        }

        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $json = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);

        if ($return) { return $json; }
    }

    /**
     * Private method to generate the base string used by cURL
     * 
     * @param string $baseURI
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $params
     * @return string Built base string
     */
    private function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) 
    {
        $return = array();
        ksort($params);

        foreach($params as $key=>$value)
        {
            $return[] = "$key=" . $value;
        }

        return $method . "&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $return)); 
    }

    /**
     * Private method to generate authorization header used by cURL
     * 
     * @param array $oauth Array of oauth data generated by buildOauth()
     * @return string $return Header used by cURL for request
     */    
    private function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) 
    {
        $return = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
        $values = array();

        foreach($oauth as $key => $value)
        {
            $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
        }
        $return .= implode(', ', $values);
        return $return;
    }

}
```

---

### Edit 1

Thanks for your reply Stormdrain. I rewrote the controller as follows but I'm getting the same error again

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->config->load('twitter_settings');
        $this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange');
        $settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => $this->config->item('oauth_access_token'),
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => $this->config->item('oauth_access_token_secret'),
            'consumer_key' => $this->config->item('consumer_key'),
            'consumer_secret' => $this->encrypt->decode($this->config->item('consumer_secret'))
        );

        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                     ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                     ->performRequest();
```

Here is the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to TwitterAPIExchange::__construct() must
>   be an array, none given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\twitter_app\theworks\core\Loader.php on line 1099 and
>   defined
>
> Filename: twitter/TwitterAPIExchange.php
>
> Line Number: 33
>
> Make sure you are passing in the correct parameters

So when I looked at line 33 of twitter/TwitterAPIExchange.php I found this:

```
/**
     * Create the API access object. Requires an array of settings::
     * oauth access token, oauth access token secret, consumer key, consumer secret
     * These are all available by creating your own application on dev.twitter.com
     * Requires the cURL library
     * 
     * @param array $settings
     */
    public function __construct(array $settings)
    { //...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redo the `$settings` with the config items

```
$this->config->load('twitter_settings');   
$this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange');
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => $this->config->('oauth_access_token'),
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => $this->config->('oauth_access_token_secret'),
    'consumer_key' => $this->config->('consumer_key'),
    'consumer_secret' => $this->config->('consumer_secret')   
    );

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply Stormdrain. I rewrote it and got the same error "...__construct() must be an array, none given..." (see EDIT 1 above)

Comment: Weird. Try printing out the `$settings` array to make sure it's getting set. before `$twitter = new Twitter...` add `print_r($settings);die;` and see what you get.

Comment: Also, did you set the encryption key in config.php? The encryption library won't work without it.

Comment: +1 Yes i set a random encryption key in the config.php. When I print_r($settings);die; the same error came up. However, when I commented out the line $this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange'); then it printed all of my keys.

Comment: And so is it working now? Were you able to `print_r` the `$settings` array?

Comment: yes it printed all of my keys but I had to comment out $this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange'); for it to print the keys

Comment: And did they look correct? That is definitely where the error is. See [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php#L45); you are getting that error message so one of those items isn't set.

Comment: +1 stormdrain, thank you very much. It is working now! $this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange', $settings); Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Basically, when you create the TwitterAPIExchange Object, you just have to pass in an **array** of strings, labelled correctly. That is all :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the library load line. Remove this:

```
$this->load->library('/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange');
```

and add library like this:

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange.php';

class Twitter extends CI_Controller{
...
}
```

This solve my issue.I have used this in php codeigniter.